# Meaning of U * S * U' in SVD?

Tags: statistics, svd

I know that the covariance of a matrix can be computed directly by using the data matrix $$Cov(Data) = X'X $$. And also can be computed via the the singular values S and V diagonal matrix of SVD that is $$Cov(Data) = V * S^2 * V' $$. The output of this matrix is a square matrix of size n; where n represents the feature dimensions of the input data.

I want to know what is the meaning of the multiplying singular values S and the U diagonal matrix that is $$ U * S * U'$$. The output of this matrix is again a square matrix of size m; where m represents the number of samples.

I am reading a code which does exactly this second calculation and the result is assigned to a variable called similarity. Is this calculation is know as some kind of distance metric between different data points ?

I would really appreciate if someone shed light on this subject.

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. Did it.

Comment: Only $X$ is intially known. So how could you evaluate the covariance matrix from $V$ and $S$ ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, V and S can be obtained by applying SVD on X. And by simply comparing $$V * S^2 * V'$$ and the $$X'X$$ we can evaluate if both have the same values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am stuck with this problem. Could you help please ?